# Error // Usage: rails new APP_PATH [options] // when running 'rails server'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade

Background info:

I'm using GIT to get a repository of a project with Ruby files in it. The project lives in my SITES folder under home directory on my Mac.

I have Ruby: 1.8.7

I have just upgraded Rails to: 3.0.3

All I am trying to accomplish is to be able to render localhost.com:3000 in my browser of the GIT project I've already downloaded so I can work on it locally.

I ran the command 'rails server' and was returned the message below::

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
      [--skip-gemfile]        # Don't create a Gemfile
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]   # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)
                              # Default: sqlite3
  -O, [--skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -J, [--skip-prototype]      # Skip Prototype files
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]      # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--dev]                 # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                              # Default: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  -G, [--skip-git]            # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]     # Path to an application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--edge]                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output

Rails options:
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Answer (score 19):

You're running `rails server` from the wrong directory. Go INTO the directory containing your app and run the command from there. For example, if you ran `rails new thingy`, you must be in the `thingy` directory when you use `rails server`.

Comment: I am getting the same error and I am in the correct directory also. Any thing else that might be causing this?

Comment: What happens if you try to run `rails c` ? What is your app name, and which directory are you running the server command from ?

Comment: Hey David I resolved it. I had to run script/server and install iconv.

Answer (score 9):

I got this when upgrading from rails 2 to rails 3 also. Then I ran `rails new .` to replace all the necessary files and it worked after that.

Answer (score 2):

Other issue could be:

You must have deleted **bin** folder from root directory or some files in it. please recover it back and all will work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Your folder director should be in Gemfile,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you clone a repository or if you are using Docker, files like `.gitignore` or `.dockerignore` has instructions for doesn't include bin folder, check in both files and simply remove the line with it.

You can execute `rails new` in another directory and copy the generated bin folder to your project and then push to your repository.