# after upgrading to rails 3, 'rails server' still just shows usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade, rails-3-upgrade

I've recently updated a rails 2.3.10 application to rails 3.0.5. I followed the rails-upgrade gem instructions. Running bundle install works fine. I've update the boot.rb application.rb and environment.rb.

```
$ bundle install
Using rake (0.8.7) 
...
Using railties (3.0.5) 
Using rails (3.0.5) 
...
```

However, when I call 'rails server' I still get usage instructions:

```
$ rails server
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? I suspect an error is getting swallowed somewhere from the upgrade procedure, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: do you have got `rails` file in your `script` folder?

Comment: The solution is here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4637366/641264](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4637366/641264)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error // Usage: rails new APP_PATH \[options\] // when running 'rails server'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637312/error-usage-rails-new-app-path-options-when-running-rails-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out a way to fix this, so I thought I'd add the step for everyone else to follow.

After doing the rails-upgrade steps:

```
rake rails:upgrade:check
rake rails:upgrade:backup
```

build a new rails app over the existing one, by doing the following WITHIN the app's directory.

```
rails_2_app $ rails new .
```

And then continue the upgrade as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete all the existing files under script folder and to create a file called rails under the same folder. The rails file should contain the following:

```
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

that's all you are good to do. You will have all the commands.