# Can't install RoR Engine for LocomoativeCMS

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines, locomotivecms

I've been following [these instructions](http://doc.locomotivecms.com/get-started/install-engine-locally#linux) from their main site. Everything works well until I get to this line:

```
$ bundle exec rails g locomotive:install
```

All that happens though is that the rails help text gets displayed. After some googling, I can see that this used to work but it doesn't anymore. It is rather vexing for a new comer to see outdated documentation.

What is the current way to set up Ruby on rails with locomotivecMS?

Comment: `rails --version`, what does it show?

Comment: it shows rails 3.2.19

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue a few days ago, following the same guide. I can't remember exactly what fixed it for me (and it was on my dev machine at home, so I can't look at it right now), but IIRC the top-rated answer from here worked for me:
[Failing to install Locomotive CMS at bundle exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911152/failing-to-install-locomotive-cms-at-bundle-exec)

While both of the listed answers may work, my basic understanding of Ruby and Bundler (I'm just learning the ecosystem) leads me to believe that the first one is better.